# Can't open localhost after configuring httpd.conf 

Tags: zend-framework

I've installed Zend Framework, and I've created my project "zendy" to the path: D:\wamp\www\zendy. So I modified the file "httpd.conf" (I use WAMPSERVER) by adding:

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
     ServerName zendy
     DocumentRoot D:\wamp\www\zendy\public
     <Directory D:\wamp\www\zendy\public>
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And then I restarted all the services of WAMPSERVER. I add a line "127.0.0.1 zendy" in the file C:\Windows\System32\divers\etc\hosts
Then I type "zendy/" or "localhost" in my navigator but it displays something like:

"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

I totally follow the tutorial for installing zend frameline like :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7svJHmgJqs and http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

Who can help me?? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: check if this helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540210/phpinternal-server-error-using-wamp-at-startup

Answer (score 1):

Verify virtual configuration syntax using “httpd -S”

Also find something like this in httpd.conf and uncomment it by removing the preceding # sign before Include

```
#Virtual hosts 
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Please don't remove the # sign before Virtual hosts as depicted above.

Also, add

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

before

```
AllowOverride All
```

and restart wamp

Comment: I tried uncomment #Virtual hosts #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf but le navigator display the information "Forbidden"

Comment: i did exactly what you wrote but it displays the same mistake "Internal Server Error"

Comment: thanks all the same, i resolve the problem. It needs to active the "rewrite_module" of Apache Server

Comment: @rishi need your help. my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949200/page-not-found-on-request-url-in-zend-2-framework-application/24952498

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zendy
    DocumentRoot D:\wamp\www\zendy\public
</VirtualHost>
```

You do not need to mention directory under this.

Try and revert! :)

PS: Also, check for AllowOverride in your main httpd.conf or apache2.conf file. Hope it helps!

Comment: @karmic i need your help. my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949200/page-not-found-on-request-url-in-zend-2-framework-application/24952498